# JavaEE EntityManager for long conversation

Tags: ejb-3.0

What is the best way to implement this use case?

Image I have got an EJB `A` which is a kind of top business process caller. It calls other beans. If during the call of other beans an exception occures, then I want to rollback everything done by the `A`.

I would image to inject the EntityManager once in the `A` bean and then pass it to other beans. It is considered to be a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use container manage transactions as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/servtran002.htm.

Put the following annotation on your A bean class: @TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)

And the following annotation on the method in A that calls other beans: @TransactionAttribute(value=REQUIRED)

And make sure other beans will throw the exception in order to roll back the transaction.

This is just a simple use case and I highly recommend to read up on EJB transaction management.

Example:

```
@Stateless
public static class A{

      @PersistenceContext(unitName="a")
      private EntityManager em = null;

      @Inject
      private B b = null;

      @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
      public void doInTransaction(){
          //get some data from em
          //modify and save back to b
          b.save(data);
      }
}

public static class B{
      @PersistenceContext(unitName="a")
      private EntityManager em = null;

      public void save(data){
          //save against em
          //catch JPA exception and throw back as RuntimeException
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks fot the tip. I read already something about transaction management. If I understand it correctly if I use the transaction management, then the injection of the entity manager is controller by it? So like when I inject beans into my `A`, specify transaction management on `A` and then inject entity manger into this other beans, then the injection is controlled by the transaction management of the `A` bean. Am I right?

Comment: EntityManager injection is controlled by EJB container and not by transaction. You dont have to pass EntityManager to other beans that A is using. They in turn should have EntitytManager being injected by container when they are created unless you are creating those beans manually in the code via "new" keyword.